# CSS scroll-behavior saying unknown property

Tags: css, smooth-scrolling

[CSS error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB3ik.png)

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBpWS.png)

Does anyone know why it says this, when I have referred to many documents?

I have a pop-up image that I want to appear from the bottom of the page and stops at the center.

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="image-wrapper">
            <div id="circle-parent" class="circle-parent" style="display: none">
                <img id="circle" class="circle" src="assets/images/thanks_for_visiting_img.png">
                <img id="close-button" class="close-button" src="assets/images/close_green.png" onclick="handleButtonClick()">
                <img id="quotes-button" class="quotes-button" src="assets/images/btn.png" onclick="handleButtonClick()">
                <div class="background">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.circle-parent {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 550px;
    height: 550px;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    max-width: none;
    max-height: none;
    cursor: default;

}
```

**JS:**

```
// window.addEventListener("load", function() {
//      const popUp = document.getElementById("circle-parent")
//     popUp.style.top = "20vh";
// })
```

Comment: scroll-behavior works on html (root element)

Comment: Still complains with the same message

Comment: it's supposed to be an instruction ;)

Answer (score 0):

Edithed according to your new (Edith).

```js
  function handleButtonClick() {
    const popUp = document.getElementById("circle-parent");
    console.log("onclick buttons work!");

    if (popUp.style.display === "none") {
      popUp.style.display = "block"; // elements visible
    } else {
      popUp.style.display = "none"; // elements hidden
    }
  }


window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    const popUp = document.getElementById("circle-parent");
    popUp.style.top = "10vh";


  // handleClose for close/get quotes button

  document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
    // if (!cookieExists()) {
    if (document.visibilityState === "hidden") {
      popUp.style.display = "none";
    } else if (document.visibilityState === "visible") {
      popUp.style.display = "block";
      // setCookie(cookieName);
    }
    //   }
    //  else {
    //   setCookie(uklFocusCookie)
    // }
  });
    });
```

```css
.circle-parent {
  position: fixed;
  left: calc(50% - 225px);
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0px;
  outline: none;
  top: 140vh;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.close-button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80%;
  top: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.quotes-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 67%;
  left: 22%;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.background {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0.83;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <div id="circle-parent" class="circle-parent">
    <img id="circle" class="circle" src="assets/images/thanks_for_visiting_img.png">
    <img id="close-button" class="close-button" src="assets/images/close_green.png" onclick="handleButtonClick()">
    <img id="quotes-button" class="quotes-button" src="assets/images/btn.png" onclick="handleButtonClick()">
    <div class="background">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="other-stuff-behind">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sapien dolor, consequat a ipsum id, pharetra mattis felis. Cras blandit urna tellus, et facilisis ante auctor vel. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
  mus. Integer sollicitudin erat ac lacus luctus consectetur. Donec ac lectus nulla. Aenean maximus rhoncus justo, ut dictum justo finibus eu. Donec dignissim erat at odio facilisis, sed placerat odio accumsan. Nulla vehicula arcu id semper
  fermentum. Nulla vel tempus nisl. Fusce efficitur viverra blandit. Nunc condimentum sodales convallis. Aliquam malesuada enim nec vestibulum vestibulum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;
  Phasellus consectetur tristique justo, quis dignissim felis dapibus id. Curabitur eu orci a odio egestas sodales. Morbi luctus metus quis ipsum pharetra gravida. Vivamus nec condimentum elit. Vivamus rutrum imperdiet nisi, pulvinar condimentum
  leo consequat nec. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer ac felis et nibh mollis porta non in augue. Phasellus sollicitudin erat ac orci auctor, eget efficitur diam pulvinar. Etiam
  eu elit ac purus interdum laoreet. Vivamus rutrum, urna sed ultrices sagittis, libero urna aliquam justo, vel tincidunt lorem quam vel est. Maecenas ut tortor nec leo vestibulum ullamcorper at vitae sem. Quisque libero nulla, vulputate in
  mauris et, tempor cursus nisi. In sed metus pulvinar tortor varius dapibus. In quis diam sagittis, dictum arcu in, congue nibh. Suspendisse interdum nisl ac risus elementum, sit amet accumsan lorem semper. Curabitur laoreet a dolor at dictum.
  Ut ac facilisis quam. Mauris ut ultricies enim, ultrices auctor lorem. Proin fermentum nisl felis, aliquet maximus urna eleifend tincidunt. Nulla quam arcu, porttitor suscipit turpis eu, dignissim varius ipsum. Nulla non urna nunc. Phasellus
  egestas laoreet leo in ultricies. Donec gravida fermentum nunc at ultrices. Integer quis lacus id enim lacinia convallis lacinia non neque. Integer molestie tempus fringilla. Suspendisse non leo pulvinar odio placerat aliquam eget sit amet
  sem. Aenean pulvinar porta diam at finibus. Aenean pellentesque orci sit amet augue imperdiet, ut sollicitudin leo accumsan. Ut aliquam tortor quis quam volutpat, pulvinar semper augue egestas. Nullam dapibus accumsan gravida. Integer euismod
  justo a elit dictum, eget pulvinar elit sagittis. Pellentesque et felis lacus. Curabitur scelerisque, mi vitae sollicitudin placerat, risus odio eleifend mi, non tincidunt nisi odio at orci. Etiam sit amet ex lacinia, molestie ligula sed,
  luctus justo. Fusce eget aliquam mi, non lobortis ex. Ut bibendum sem sapien, sed placerat justo hendrerit in. Etiam mi nisi, interdum ut malesuada vitae, tempus at ipsum. Praesent quis turpis pharetra, tincidunt magna id, aliquet leo. Nullam
  mollis mi at interdum lacinia. Maecenas ut magna feugiat, euismod augue eget, posuere diam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis fringilla interdum cursus. Sed nisi massa, ultricies vitae blandit et, sodales ut mauris. Sed sed metus diam.
  Nullam vestibulum consectetur facilisis. Morbi in purus commodo, congue urna eu, interdum metus. Duis dolor dui, elementum id rhoncus ac, ultrices ac libero. Vivamus vestibulum blandit consequat. In at turpis ut augue efficitur tristique nec
  sed erat. Sed fermentum augue eget ipsum convallis ornare. Nullam ut tortor risus. Maecenas consequat pharetra porttitor. Proin nec odio rhoncus, aliquam metus id, laoreet arcu. Nullam ullamcorper magna sit amet metus consectetur, at mollis
  ex tincidunt. Donec consequat purus dui, in laoreet libero cursus quis. Fusce ut felis sit amet velit tempus lobortis. Vestibulum sed eleifend urna, quis vestibulum nulla. Sed at scelerisque risus. Maecenas molestie massa eget felis vehicula
  accumsan. Sed feugiat in dolor sit amet placerat. Morbi lacinia ante ac lacus pretium consectetur et eu odio. Pellentesque tempus pretium rhoncus. Praesent at faucibus neque. Nulla sed est sit amet ex feugiat iaculis vel vitae lectus. Donec
  tempus elit eu turpis porta viverra. Suspendisse commodo nisl purus, nec ultricies lorem commodo et. Vivamus lacinia porttitor enim a efficitur. Cras porttitor justo id sem auctor dignissim. Morbi ut ante et augue convallis pellentesque viverra
  ac felis. Morbi non bibendum nunc. Vivamus nec vehicula ipsum. Sed dictum felis eget est condimentum, at sodales eros aliquet. Proin maximus ut sem at iaculis. Nulla ex purus, viverra posuere arcu non, bibendum condimentum arcu. In tortor
  felis, molestie non pharetra at, malesuada vitae ligula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas posuere, urna a rutrum efficitur, ante eros maximus dolor, ac consequat quam ante ut est. Ut aliquam, nulla fringilla
  convallis consectetur, nisi dolor semper risus, quis vestibulum elit felis eget metus. Quisque egestas ultricies tempor. Phasellus sodales sem vitae justo facilisis, sit amet commodo diam gravida. Aenean cursus mi mauris, quis accumsan leo
  sodales blandit. Cras sed sollicitudin velit. Donec eleifend mauris id eros fermentum porta. Integer luctus dolor nunc, sit amet semper nisi convallis vitae. Vivamus in sem ex. Fusce eu efficitur mauris, at pretium ligula. Sed dignissim, dolor
  quis iaculis sagittis, nibh ex scelerisque mauris, sed faucibus nibh augue at mi. Aenean ultricies ac tortor eu sagittis. Sed facilisis sodales eros, et commodo ante vestibulum nec. Sed posuere condimentum pellentesque. Nulla vehicula tincidunt
  nisl vitae finibus. Nunc erat dolor, pretium dictum commodo ultricies, aliquam a mauris. Fusce eget aliquam mi, non lobortis ex. Ut bibendum sem sapien, sed placerat justo hendrerit in. Etiam mi nisi, interdum ut malesuada vitae, tempus at
  ipsum. Praesent quis turpis pharetra, tincidunt magna id, aliquet leo. Nullam mollis mi at interdum lacinia. Maecenas ut magna feugiat, euismod augue eget, posuere diam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis fringilla interdum cursus. Sed
  nisi massa, ultricies vitae blandit et, sodales ut mauris. Sed sed metus diam. Nullam vestibulum consectetur facilisis. Morbi in purus commodo, congue urna eu, interdum metus. Duis dolor dui, elementum id rhoncus ac, ultrices ac libero. Vivamus
  vestibulum blandit consequat. In at turpis ut augue efficitur tristique nec sed erat. Sed fermentum augue eget ipsum convallis ornare. Nullam ut tortor risus. Maecenas consequat pharetra porttitor. Proin nec odio rhoncus, aliquam metus id,
  laoreet arcu. Nullam ullamcorper magna sit amet metus consectetur, at mollis ex tincidunt. Donec consequat purus dui, in laoreet libero cursus quis. Fusce ut felis sit amet velit tempus lobortis. Vestibulum sed eleifend urna, quis vestibulum
  nulla. Sed at scelerisque risus. Maecenas molestie massa eget felis vehicula accumsan. Sed feugiat in dolor sit amet placerat. Morbi lacinia ante ac lacus pretium consectetur et eu odio. Pellentesque tempus pretium rhoncus. Praesent at faucibus
  neque. Nulla sed est sit amet ex feugiat iaculis vel vitae lectus. Donec tempus elit eu turpis porta viverra. Suspendisse commodo nisl purus, nec ultricies lorem commodo et. Vivamus lacinia porttitor enim a efficitur. Cras porttitor justo
  id sem auctor dignissim. Morbi ut ante et augue convallis pellentesque viverra ac felis. Morbi non bibendum nunc. Vivamus nec vehicula ipsum. Sed dictum felis eget est condimentum, at sodales eros aliquet. Proin maximus ut sem at iaculis.
  Nulla ex purus, viverra posuere arcu non, bibendum condimentum arcu. In tortor felis, molestie non pharetra at, malesuada vitae ligula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas posuere, urna a rutrum efficitur, ante
  eros maximus dolor, ac consequat quam ante ut est. Ut aliquam, nulla fringilla convallis consectetur, nisi dolor semper risus, quis vestibulum elit felis eget metus. Quisque egestas ultricies tempor. Phasellus sodales sem vitae justo facilisis,
  sit amet commodo diam gravida. Aenean cursus mi mauris, quis accumsan leo sodales blandit. Cras sed sollicitudin velit. Donec eleifend mauris id eros fermentum porta. Integer luctus dolor nunc, sit amet semper nisi convallis vitae. Vivamus
  in sem ex. Fusce eu efficitur mauris, at pretium ligula. Sed dignissim, dolor quis iaculis sagittis, nibh ex scelerisque mauris, sed faucibus nibh augue at mi. Aenean ultricies ac tortor eu sagittis. Sed facilisis sodales eros, et commodo
  ante vestibulum nec. Sed posuere condimentum pellentesque. Nulla vehicula tincidunt nisl vitae finibus. Nunc erat dolor, pretium dictum commodo ultricies, aliquam a mauris.
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly like that but without the needing to scroll. It just does the animation instead?

Comment: when should start the animation? by click?

Comment: It's just automatically when the user has landed on the page.

Comment: I appreciate your help! I'm nearly there. I just put my code back to how it was because it was breaking everything haha. Do I just need to take the transition css from your code and add it to mine? I've edited my post to include the code

Comment: Circle parent is the image itself

Comment: I just changed it but there's no transition

Comment: it has transition whenever you load the page

Comment: Ah it's meant to be when they have switched tabs and then gone back on the page ://

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. can you create a fiddle?

Comment: I haven't used fiddle before and I tried creating one but it wont display my images. :/ 
I'll see if more context helps. I have edited my post at the top and if you look at 'image here' that's the image that should transition from the bottom to the center of the page. 

This image only appears once every 7 days (due to a cookie). The Lorem Ipsum text behind the image is an example of the website which will always be on display.

Comment: When the user switches tab and views another website, then they come back the website (with the lorem ipsum text) then the pop up image should appear but transition from the bottom to the center.

Comment: This is all the code in fiddle, even though images doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/KirstLMC/m19v8yjd/6/

Comment: Can anyone help please? :(

Comment: @KirstyM Edithed according to your new (Code-Edith).